# How to make parameter conditional inside interface with generic type interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to build an interface, for example, Dropdown props interface for React component, and I'm trying to make params optional only if T generic is string.
My research found zero answers for my question.

[image]

as you can see here, I'm trying to make getTemplate optional only if T extends string type, but if it something else I will have to write it.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. param with undefined type is not optional parameter, it is parameter with undefined.

Any suggestions? Thanks ahead.

here an example of something I tried but doesn't work:

```
type Props<T extends string | Omit<any, 'string'>> = (T extends string
? {}
: {
      getTemplate: (item: T) => ReactNode;
      getDisplayTemplate(item: T): ReactNode;
      getItemIdentifier(item: T): string | number;
  }) & {
items: Array<T>;
disabled?: boolean;
className?: string;
placeholder?: string;
selectedItems: Array<T>;
isMultiSelect?: boolean;
onChange(items: Array<T>): void;
```

};

```
export const Dropdown = <T,>({
disabled,
placeholder,
selectedItems = [],
items,
onChange,
getDisplayTemplate,
getItemIdentifier,
getTemplate,
isMultiSelect,
className,
```

}: Props) => {

Comment: Please paste your original code next time instead of using image.

Comment: Noted, thanks will be done next time. I'll edit the post right now

Answer (score 1):

Maybe extract the conditional part into a member of a union type. Make `getTemplate`, etc. optional only if `T` is a string.

```
type ConditionalProps<T> = {
      getTemplate: (item: T) => ReactNode;
      getDisplayTemplate(item: T): ReactNode;
      getItemIdentifier(item: T): string | number;
};
type Props<T> =
(T extends string ? Partial<ConditionalProps<T>> : ConditionalProps<T>) & {
    items: Array<T>;
    disabled?: boolean;
    className?: string;
    placeholder?: string;
    selectedItems: Array<T>;
    isMultiSelect?: boolean;
    onChange(items: Array<T>): void;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried it but I think it doesnt work also. I can't extract the functions when i use the componet

Comment: @EdenBinyamin It's difficult to help you without seeing the code and the actual error, but if you type the props with a type parameter like `props: Props<MyClass>`, you should be able to access `props.getTemplate`.

Comment: wrote it on the post itself, sorry man